# How to change screen states in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to change the state of the screen from Menu to PlayState by pressing `space`, but when `space` is pressed the program seems to be in some loop as it keeps on drawing things in the playstate.
Here is the code:

```
public class Main {

    public enum ScreenState {MENU, PLAYSTATE, RESET}

    static ScreenState screenState = ScreenState.MENU;

    static Menu menu = new Menu();


    public static void main(String[] args) {



//        Setting default canvas
        StdDraw.clear();
        StdDraw.setCanvasSize(800, 700);
        StdDraw.setXscale(0, 800);
        StdDraw.setYscale(0, 700);
        StdDraw.filledRectangle(0,0,800,700);

        while(true) {

          switch (screenState) {
            case MENU:
              menu.drawMenu();
              //        starts game
              if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed(' ')) {
               screenState = ScreenState.PLAYSTATE;
              }

              break;

            case PLAYSTATE:

              StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
              StdDraw.filledRectangle(0,0,800,700);
              StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.WHITE);
              StdDraw.text(50,680,"SCORE");

              break;  
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a tag for your user-interface kit, such as Swing, JavaFX, Vaadin, etc.

Comment: Once you press space, it goes to the playstate.  But then there's no way to get out of the playstate.  So I'm not surprised you get in a loop, stuck in the playstate.

Comment: capitalization, added missing full stop.